# Font is not switching/changing when language is changed react-native ios

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fonts, internationalization

My react-native app has 2 languages- Hindi and English. For English I am using Inter as font and for Hindi it is supposed to be Noto. Any idea how should I proceed with this in ios.

For android it is working.
Approach:

```
export const IMSetFonts = (langCode?: any) => {
  if (!!langCode && langCode !== 'en') fonts = Fonts.Noto;
  else fonts = Fonts.Inter;

  FontStyles.heading.h1.fontFamily = fonts.semiBold;
}
```

Can anyone help with why is this approach not working on ios

When I switch language from English to Hindi. I also want the font to switch from Inter to Noto

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are your fonts properly linked in ios?